# Is it possible to make an ImGui window non compressable?

Tags: imgui

I'm looking for an ImGui window flag that would allow a docked window to display an icon of a fixed size, and the user should not be able to compress the window edges past the borders of the icon. So no matter how small the window is, the icon should always be there. Is there such a flag in ImGui? I can't seem to find anything online.